# Confusion about division in rates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

I would really appreciate help with this because it's been driving me insane for a while now...

I understand what "per" means in "$x$ kilometers *per* $y$ hours". What I don't understand is how to make the use of the division bar in rates coherent with the definition of division.

Based on my understanding of division, it would mean in this case: "how many times do $y$ hours fit into $x$ kilometers?", which doesn't make any sense to me.

How do you make sense of dividing a certain kind of unit by a completely different kind? Do you think of it as a different kind of division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have $\frac{5}{2}$, we can either think of this in terms of "How many lots of 2 fit into 5?", as you said, but you could also think of it in terms of "If I break 5 into 2 groups, how many will be in each group?".

The 2nd definition makes your question much more clear. If I travel $100km$ in $2hrs$, rather than thinking "How many lots of $2 hrs$ can I fit into $100km$?" which sounds a bit weird like you said, you can say "If I break my $100km$ into $2hrs$, how many km will be in each hour?".

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot more sense, thank you. I think I was confused because I always thought that units had to be the same when doing any kind of operations between numbers; for ex you cant add apples to oranges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is exactly division.  You divide $x$, whose units are kilometers, by $y$, whose units are hours, to get $\frac{x}{y}$, whose units are kilometers per hour or km/h.

When you are in a car, and the spedometer says 100 kph or km/h, that means your rate of travel is 100.  If you maintain that rate for one hour, you will travel 100 kilometers.  That is:

(100 km/h)(1 h) = 100 (km$\cdot$h/h)=100 km.

Comment: But how does it make sense to divide two completely different units? You can't divide 4 apples by 2 oranges, it doesn't mean anything. Do you know what I mean?